# what property to set so that browser doesnot rename the "IDs"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

what property to set so that browser doesnot rename the "IDs" ?

how to stop the browser from remaining the ids of eleent which are within the "web user control"?

Comment: Could you elaborate on your question? What IDs are being renamed?

Comment: I don't think the browser does it. I believe it's .NET.

Comment: @user: it's ASP.NET, and that's how it's meant to work.

Comment: k, linkbutton ids are renamed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set the ClientIDMode. And it is not browser but asp.net that sets the ids.

```
Dim panel As New Panel
panel.ClientIDMode = UI.ClientIDMode.Static
```

You can also set this in the Control or Page declaration section, to apply it to the whole page/control.

Answer (score 3):

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Note that this only works in .NET 4.0.

Comment: Note:That feature is available only with .NET 4

Comment: @conqenator - Forgot to mention that for a second. You must have typed that while I was editing. :)

Comment: Yeah, thought so.:)  I'll upvote this now since it seems complete.